# Source code in memory rather than file for GDB

Tags: gdb, elf, jit, dwarf, tcc

I'm writing a JIT that compiles c fragments using libtcc to an ELF object (output type `TCC_OUTPUT_OBJ`) with dwarf-5 debug info, loads the resulting ELF object manually (mapping, relocating and linking with the process image, resolving symbols from the process image but not exporting any back).  I plan to let GDB know about the loaded ELF using its [JIT interface](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/JIT-Interface.html).

The JIT ELF objects are ephemeral, and are unmapped and freed when their reference counts (from other objects) drop to zero, and the c source for them is typically machine generated and doesn't exist in any file.

My question is: is there any way to provide GDB with the generated c source code in memory rather than having to maintain the active JIT ELF objects' source code in temporary files (with all the cleanup concerns that implies)?